# wp-cli fails on installing to subdomain

Tags: installation, wp-cli

it's likely I missed something, but I just tried to use wp-cli to install Wordpress on a subdomain.

After succesfully downloading, creating wp-config and calling the install procedure with:

```
wp core install --url=http://sub.example.com --title=title --admin_user=admin --admin_password=password --admin_email=admin@example.com --skip-email
```

, I CAN open the new Wordpress-Site but all URL's seem to be wrong.

**What should be**: sub.example.com

**is**: sub.example.comexample.com

Probably the url is parsed "tld and then to the next dot" and I can repair the installation with:

```
wp search-replace sub.example.comexample.com sub.example.com --skip-columns=guid
```

In a way I can live with this, but it seems somewhat wrong to me.

Is there a better way like an extra parameter or something for wp core install?